# ui header is blocking a div

Tags: jquery, user-interface, header, tabs, floating

i have built jQuery drop-down menu which is having problems floating over the UI header. Flash and everything else is fine, menu has no problem floating over anything except UI headers, i have tried messing with z-index in css files but it seems that jQuery script is over writing all of my css. the JS files are minified so i can not edit them. I think a JS solution is necessary but i do not know how to solve this with JS.

URL: http://patel.mine.nu/live%20site/metanoia/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it with `z-index`, just make sure that you *position* the elements to which you add a `z-index`, otherwise it won't work.

Add to your top menu: `position:relative; z-index:1;`
And to the bar in the middle: `position:relative; z-index:0;`

If I change this live in Safari's Web Inspector it seems to work.

Comment: thank you! i just needed to place the css index for menu after the css for "UI Tabs". And yes, i already has specified position for both so now it works.

Answer (score 0):

add this css

## stndtm{

z-index:10000;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
list-style-image:none;
list-style-position:outside;
list-style-type:none;
padding:0.2em 0.2em 0;
position:relative;
z-index:500;
}

in your main file it should work

Comment: I didn't need to specify the z-index for ui classes, just needed to add one for div after the UI css was loaded, which fixed the problem, but thank you for your reply.